# XJB [ERROR] Multiple <schemaBindings> are defined for the target namespace

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I have multiple XSD files, and I want to run an XJC over them to create java class objects, which I use for further processing.
**ISSUE:**
2 XSDs among my set of XSDs have an issue when I run the XJC command. The XSDs are:

**contactLM.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:w="http://w.com/xsd" 
            xmlns="http://w.com/location.contactlm" 
            xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
            targetNamespace="http://w.com/location.contactlm" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified" jaxb:version="2.1">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
      <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="location.contactlm"/> 
      </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>

  <xsd:element name="Contact" type="Contact" nillable="true"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="Contact">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="RefID" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" 
                   minOccurs="0" gw:type="java.lang.String"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>


</xsd:schema>
```

**contactM.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:w="http://w.com/xsd"
      xmlns="http://w.com/location.contactm"
      targetNamespace="http://w.com/location.contactm"
      elementFormDefault="qualified"
      xmlns:ns0="http://w.com/location.contactam"
      xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"  
      jaxb:version="2.1">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
      <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="location.contactm"/>
      </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://w.com/location.contactam"
              schemaLocation="ContactAM.xsd"/>
  <xsd:element name="Contact" type="Contact" nillable="true"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="Contact">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="RefID" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" 
                   type="xsd:string" gw:type="java.lang.String"/>
      <xsd:element name="WorkPhone" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" 
                   type="xsd:string" gw:type="java.lang.String"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I know there is a reference to the same "contact" in these XSD files, and THAT is an issue. SO, I had  to write my XJB file. 
I have the following xjb file written:

```
<jaxb:bindings
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:gw="http://w.com/xsd" 
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns="http://w.com/location.contactlm" 

  targetNamespace="http://w.com/location.contactlm" 
  jaxb:version="2.1">

     <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="ContactM.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='Contact']">
            <jaxb:class name="ContactM"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="location.contactm" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="ContactLM.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='Contact']">
            <jaxb:class name="ContactCLM"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="location.contactlm" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

but i get the following error when I do:

```
xjc -d src -b C:\us\binding.xjb C:\us\trunk\shared\


parsing a schema...
346368376 / 346685920 (-1 / -1) (com/sun/tools/internal/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/CollectionTypeAttribute$JaxbAccessorF_collectionType/com/sun/tools/internal/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/CollectionTyp
eAttribute$JaxbAccessorF_collectionType)
[ERROR] Multiple <schemaBindings> are defined for the target namespace "http://w.com/location.contactm"
  line 10 of file:/C:/us/trunk/contact/ContactM.xsd

[ERROR] Another <schemaBindings> is defined here
  line 14 of file:/C:/us/trunk/contact/binding.xjb

[ERROR] Multiple <schemaBindings> are defined for the target namespace "http://w.com//trunk/contactlm"
  line 5 of file:/C:/us/trunk/contact/ContactLM.xsd

[ERROR] Another <schemaBindings> is defined here
  line 23 of file:/C:/us/trunk/contact/binding.xjb

[ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this schemaBinding customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
  line 14 of file:/C:/us/trunk/contact/binding.xjb

[ERROR] (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)
  line 10 of file:/C:/us/trunk/contact/ContactM.xsd

[ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this schemaBinding customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
  line 23 of file:/C:/us/trunk/contact/binding.xjb

[ERROR] (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)
  line 2 of file:/C:/us/trunk/contact/ContactLM.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

I guess I might be doing something wrong in the XJB file, but I'm unable to fix the issue. Someone please help.

Comment: Your first two error messages are saying that Jaxb is finding two schemaBindings elements for each of your two namespaces -- one in the xjb file and one in the XSD schema document.  Ask yourself (and ask the documentation, and in a pinch ask the JAXB compiler): do I really need to say this twice?  Or would once suffice?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen Thanks for the response. I was worried as to why no one was even responding! :-(
As for, do I need two schema docs, Yes, because, the one I wrote in the xjb file overrrides the XSD schema doc. At least, that's what I understood from reading the manuals. Please let me know if this is wrong.

Comment: My other concern is, is my XJB file wrong? I have composed my xjb file from all the knowledge I could gather from various sources on the internet. In other words, its a hodgepodge from various sources. I have a feeling that something could be wrong in the file. Do you have anything to say about it?

Comment: I'm not a JAXB expert; I can only give you general advice.  Experiment with different configurations.  First make the simplest test case you can that produces this error message. (Once you understand the problem, fixing your real setup will be easy.)  Your task is to fix a bug; work as systematically as you would work on a bug in your Java.  JaxB sees a conflict; try to find and resolve it.  Try suppressing the inline annotation, then the external annotation; is JaxB happy then?  Suppress the `jaxb:package` element (inline, or external); then suppress `jaxb:schemaBindings`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mainly need to do is remove the scheme binding from your xsd files. I've copied and tested your files and it worked. However, I changed the reference to `ContactAM` to `ContactLM`assuming it was a typo.

Here are my files:

### ContactM.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:gw="http://w.com/xsd"
      xmlns="http://w.com/location.contactm"
      targetNamespace="http://w.com/location.contactm"
      elementFormDefault="qualified"
      xmlns:ns0="http://w.com/location.contactam"
      xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"  
      jaxb:version="2.1">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
<!--       <jaxb:schemaBindings> -->
<!--         <jaxb:package name="location.contactm"/> -->
<!--       </jaxb:schemaBindings> -->
    </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://w.com/location.contactlm"
              schemaLocation="ContactLM.xsd"/>
  <xsd:element name="Contact" type="Contact" nillable="true"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="Contact">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="RefID" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" 
                   type="xsd:string" gw:type="java.lang.String"/>
      <xsd:element name="WorkPhone" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" 
                   type="xsd:string" gw:type="java.lang.String"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

### ContactLM.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:gw="http://w.com/xsd" 
            xmlns="http://w.com/location.contactlm" 
            xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
            targetNamespace="http://w.com/location.contactlm" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified" jaxb:version="2.1">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
<!--       <jaxb:schemaBindings> -->
<!--         <jaxb:package name="location.contactm"/> -->
<!--       </jaxb:schemaBindings> -->
    </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>

  <xsd:element name="Contact" type="Contact" nillable="true"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="Contact">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="RefID" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" 
                   minOccurs="0" gw:type="java.lang.String"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>


</xsd:schema>
```

and finally the binding file:

### bind.xjb

```
<jaxb:bindings
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:gw="http://w.com/xsd" 
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns="http://w.com/location.contactlm" 

  targetNamespace="http://w.com/location.contactlm" 
  jaxb:version="2.1">

     <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="ContactM.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='Contact']">
            <jaxb:class name="ContactM"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="location.contactm" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="ContactLM.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='Contact']">
            <jaxb:class name="ContactCLM"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="location.contactlm" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

And for completeness, here's my command and its output

```
D:\stackoverflow\sample>xjc ContactM.xsd -b bind.xjb
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
location\contactm\Contact.java
location\contactm\ContactM.java
location\contactm\ObjectFactory.java
location\contactm\package-info.java
location\contactlm\Contact.java
location\contactlm\ContactCLM.java
location\contactlm\ObjectFactory.java
location\contactlm\package-info.java
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a set of files that I am not allowed to edit the xsd files and the file has a targetNamespace="namespace1", then imports namespace="namespace2".  Do you know how to rectify this without changing the xsd file"?